# Querer no basta, hay que saber cómo ayudar

Tags: discusión

En **[una publicación reciente](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/44261/programa-en-el-que-nunca-se-sale-del-main-bucle-infinito)** vi una respuesta que no era una respuesta. **Era un comentario.**

Su respuesta decia: "has probado a darle a intro o solo has introducido el numero sin más" (estoy parafraseando, no la recuerdo a la perfección)

Procedí a reportarla y como el autor tenia poca Rep (15) me dispuse a explicarle que la había reportado y el porqué.

Él(no recuerdo su nombre de usuario y borró su "respuesta") **pareció indignado**. Me dijo que sólo **trataba de ayudarle**.

Le dije que **eso no justificaba que pusiera como respuesta**, un comentario. A lo que él me contestó: No puede publicar un comentario, por eso hice una respuesta.

Repetí que eso no justificaba que lo pusiera como respuesta. Su contestación fue la ultima, ya que como dije antes borró la "repuesta". Y me dijo algo asi como: **Vale, ya no vuelvo a ayudar más**.

Espero que no lo haya dicho en serio.. :/

Estaba a punto de darle a a enter a mi comentario cuando me salió el aviso de Respuesta borrada.

Queria decirle que me alegra que quiera ayudar. Que se leyera el Tour y El centro de ayuda. Que para que todo vaya bien, has de saber cómo funciona ésto.

---

Y esto va para aquellos que también quieren ayudar, dejando un solo link a la documentacion, o pegando un cacho de código sin explicación alguna.

Las ganas de ayudar las tienes, ahora **aprende a cómo ayudar**.

Comment: Yo personalmente, cuando veo a un usuario nuevo(que generalmente no lee nada de lo que le digas) que ha escrito una respuesta que más bien debe ser un comentario, antes que todo le doy las gracias por querer ayudar y le digo que su respuesta no está completa y que en cuanto tenga mas reputación ya puede comentar, sin embargo jamás lo reporto ni le doy -1 ya que eso los auyenta. :( Al contrario los invito a seguir apoyando, pero bueno, ese soy yo.

Comment: @x4mp73r puede ser como dices  pero yo lo veo distinto. Si diera "-1" o si se borrara su respuesta sin más , seria perjudicial para él. pero diciendolo por qué no debería ahuyentarse...

Comment: Siendo nuevo es muy difícil "ayudar" ya que no se pueden agregar comentarios, y si se es muy entusiasta se agrega una respuesta que es mas un comentario, a mi me paso, y creo que a todos en algún momento, cuando empezaron, por lo que pienso que si es alguien con muy poca reputación hay que instruirle sin que se sienta ofendido, porque muchas veces la forma de como dicen las cosas suena muy "regañado" y si desanima a seguir

Comment: @lois6b con los nuevos usuarios hay que ser un poco mas _comprensivos_ ya que no están familiarizados con el sistema de Stack Overflow en Español. En una próxima oportunidad, comparte al usuario algunos enlaces de ayuda como: "[revisar el tour/recorrido](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour), [ser amable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice)", "[MCVE](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)", etc.

Comment: @EzequieleezzeklCanul tienes razon, puede sonar como riña pero para nada. que te digan que algo está mal no es nada malo.

Comment: @Mauricio si, me disponia a ponerle enlaces cuando eliminó la public v.v

Comment: No digo que este mal el corregir. solo digo que muchas veces esa corrección suena a regaño, tengan en cuenta que no ven (vemos) con que "animos" esta diciendo las cosas la otra persona

Comment: ¿Dónde se aprende a ayudar?

Comment: @toledano en el centro de ayuda, meta, etc... no es muy común con 15 de rep visitar estos sitios

Comment: Creo que eso le falta a tu publicación. Después de tu anécdota, concluyes que lo que se necesita es aprender a ayudar, pero no aportas recursos para lograr este objetivo. Por cierto que el centro de ayuda contiene excelente documentación para aprender a usar el sitio, pero no me queda claro que funcionen para resolver el problema que comentas en tu historia.

Comment: @toledano bueno, mencioné que le iba a pasar links a esas paginas que te digo. y si, en el centro de ayuda hay explicaciones de "preguntas aceptables", "como hacer buenas respuestas" ...

Comment: Si yo le voy a decir a alguien, cómo preguntar o cómo responder, no lo redirijo a links que ni yo he visto en todo el tiempo que llevo en StackOverflow. Prefiero decirle cómo puede hacer que su pregunta o su respuesta esté más acorde.

Comment: por eso siempre recomiendo que den un paseo por el tour del sitio, eso ayuda a que tengan la mente un poco más abierta. Por otro lado, cuando veamos usuarios con menos de 100 puntos, primero vamos dejando en claro que los comentarios que nosotros podamos redactar van en buen plan para mantener el orden del sitio y que agradecemos su colaboración :D (y sí, al poner una carita feliz como que le cambia el estado de la lectura, por eso siempre las pongo, hasta porque sí :D venga, vamos en Buena onda entre todos :D ) espero que este tipo de situacion eviten repetirse. Saludos!

Answer (score 2):

Enseñar siempre es mejor que criticar, así en un caso así diría al usuario que una sugerencia o una idea sería algo para un comentario, pero no para una respuesta. De una respuesta uno espera un poco más detalles y un poco más guía.

Una respuesta también puede ser una sugerencia, pero debería ser mucho más elaborado y el autor por lo menos debería tener buenas razones para sugerir el método. No hay gran drama si no funciona, si esta bien documentado, porque el usuario que hizo la pregunta puede comentar que no le ha ayudado el método. Una buena idea aun que no comprobado puede ser una respuesta valida, eso depende al fin si funciona o no. No hay que olvidar que a veces (lo he visto en SO ingles) aun que la solución no funcionó al usuario que hizo la pregunta en primer lugar, si funcionó a otros, que tuvieron un problema parecido, pero con contextos un poco cambiados.

En el fondo pienso que hay que aplicar criterio - si puede ser útil, déjalo. Solamente si es evidentemente tontería se debe actuar. Aquí tambien viene otro aspecto de la moderación: hay un botón "omitir", y este botón es para los casos en que no estoy seguro si puedo evaluar si la respuesta es simplemente idiota, o si quizas yo solamente no capto suficiente del tema para estar seguro. En el caso de duda: deja la decisión a alguien que sabe más que tu del tema. Casi siempre hay, nadie puede ser especialista en todo.

Comment: tengo una pregunta con recompensa, si nadie me resolvio mi duda debo dar recompensa?, ya se que no tiene nada que ver con tu respuesta, pero nose a quien preguntar

Comment: Según yo eso es 100% a tu criterio. Si ninguna respuesta te resuelve el problema, no veo ninguna razón para recompensar. Porque no haces una pregunta propia en meta de eso? Creo que la pregunta es interesante para todos.

Answer (score -4):

Cuando tienes poco nivel no pudes acceder a los comentarios. Agregas una respuesta pidiendo especificaciones tratando de ayudar, por ello eres puntuado negativo; se es dificil ayudar creo que todos deberiamos tener acceso a escribir algun comentario tal vez validarlo por alguien con mas nivel

Comment: En efecto, puede ser frustrante no poder comentar cuando uno comienza. Pero es solo cuestión de ser paciente. Después de publicar algunas buenas respuestas, o hasta buenas preguntas, rápidamente llegarás a los 50 puntos requeridos para poder comentar.

Comment: Piensa que el limite de 50 puntos no es para molestar a los nuevos. Eso no tendria sentido alguno. Hay muchos spamers, trolls, e idiotas rematados que utilizan los comentarios para estropear publicaciones. Y cuando les borras la cuenta crean otra. El limite de 50 está para eso. Ademas como dice @sstan, un poco paciente y un par de buenas respuestas y ahi estás ya. Respecto a lo que dices de revisar comentarios, no lo veo viable. ya cuesta tener limpia la revision de preguntas/respuestas  y votos como para añadir comentarios, que hay muchos mas. Solo me queda decirte: Animo . Un saludo

Comment: no crees que promueven el NO participar

Comment: @JackNavaRow no, promuevo el participar correctamente.

Comment: si es asi. por que la puntuacion negativa?, es una respuesta aceptada al tema